# Load content after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a page with some content. When it opens, I want to display only the first div, and load all the others after scrolling 500 px from top.  How to do that?

The goal is to delay loading the content, not just hide it

Code exampe:

```
 <div id="first_loaded"></div>
    <div id="loaded_after_scrolling"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWD66/2478/) with your example.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#loaded_after_scrolling").hide();
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
       if($(window).scrollTop()>500) {
           $("#loaded_after_scrolling").fadeIn();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx for the fade-in effect. It works, but the page has the same size! The goal is to DELAY LOADING the content, not just hide it.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500)
    {
      // load div content here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/gWD66/2489/